# Stochastic gradient descent is basically ordinary gradient descent?

Tags: neural-network

I have did some reach and calculation and If I understand correctly, Stochastic gradient descent - "Adam optimiser" is basically ordinary gradient descent, with one specific that it selects a random data in smaller proportion with training dataset, to avoid NN being caught in gap, which might not necessary reflect minimum value in descent function? Thank you

Comment: Is your question not covered at wikipedia? ```to avoid NN being caught in gap``` is the least of all reasons for this usage. Different convergence-properties and memory-usage is much more important (and your *beeing caught in gap* is not well understood yet theory-wise, although that's also true for convergence in general with non-convex losses). Adam is also not vanilla-SGD. It's a variant trying to improve convergence (like classic momentum and co.) under some assumptions (it's more or less some kind of filter).

Comment: Thank you Sascha. I haven't been thinking about memory usage. Correct.

Answer (score 0):

`Stochastic Gradient Descent` is generally juxtaposed with `Batch Gradient Descent`. 
In **Batch** Mode,to update each feature co--efficient of the input feature vector *X*, you need a summation over **ALL** the records of your training data set,
*source: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf*

```
Repeat until convergence 
{
  θj := θj + α * summation(i=1 to m) ( y - h(x) ) x_j  --> for every j
}
```

The important thing here is that the summation over ALL the records is done for each feature, so if you have 5000 features/attributes/columns of your data  , you are performing the sum 5000 times for each run.

In contrast, if you look at *stochastic*,

```
Loop
{
    for i=1 to m, {
         θj := θj + α(  y(i) − h(x(i))  x(i) j (for every j).
    }
 }
```

Essentially, for each j, only that particular feature or value of X considered.
That makes it fast.
The con is that, it may not have the same minima as batch, or global minima may not be achieved, but in practice it does tend to work better.